# Asyncio set event loop make freeze

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I am creating an application in python and i need to create channel with telegram, for make this, i use telethon:

```
async def createChannel(username, desc):
try:
    chn = await client(CreateChannelRequest(username,desc,megagroup=False))
    new_channel_id = chn.chats[0].id
    new_channel_access_hash = chn.chats[0].access_hash
    update_response = await client(UpdateUsernameRequest(
            InputPeerChannel(channel_id=new_channel_id,
                            access_hash=new_channel_access_hash), username))
except:
    await client.connect()
    chn = await client(CreateChannelRequest(username,desc,megagroup=False))
    new_channel_id = chn.chats[0].id
    new_channel_access_hash = chn.chats[0].access_hash
    update_response = await client(UpdateUsernameRequest(
            InputPeerChannel(channel_id=new_channel_id,
                            access_hash=new_channel_access_hash), username))
return update_response
```

I want to use multi threading but when i do that, i got error that say me "No event loop in the thread", so ask google and he gave me this:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

But when i have this and my multi threading, it just stuck and do nothing at this line:

```
chn = await client(CreateChannelRequest(username,desc,megagroup=False))
```

Any idea? thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing the `client` object, you should pass the event loop to `TelegramClient` like:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
client = TelegramClient(..., loop=loop)
```